# How to use htaccess to rewrite to file from an empty directory

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cdsite/register/
RewriteRule ^.*$ /cdsite/register/register.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

That is my .htaccess file's contents. What i would like to do, if possible, is redirect to the register.php file from any input following the register directory's designation, including no input (i.e. myawesomesite.com/cdsite/register/ or myawesomesite.com/cdsite/register/randominput)

I have tried doing both no input or a random input, but neither are working. I am testing on MAMP local server and my other htaccess rewrites work fine. MY htaccess file is located in the register directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to register.php
RewriteRule .* /cdsite/register/register.php [L]
```

What you're doing here is to check and see if the file they are trying to access actually exists.  If the file does not exist, then redirect to `register.php`.  The reason I am adding this in is because you are saying in your title that the directory is empty, however, you are referencing `register.php` inside of that directory.  So hopefully that file exists.

If it's a problem with your paths or maybe it's just not redirecting properly, you can try using the full URL like this:

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/cdsite/register/register.php [L]
```

Comment: It works with the exception if the "fake directory" in the url is entered with an empty input. For example: "myawesomesite.com/cdsite/register/randominput" works, where as "myawesomesite.com/cdsite/register/" will not bring me to register.php

Comment: Huh, weird.  I read your note and so set it up on a server here at work and tried it, setting my RewriteRule to redirect over to Google if it met the conditions.  Whether I went to `http://domain.com/folder/something_that_doesn't_exist`, `http://domain.com/folder/` or `http://domain.com/folder`, they all redirected to Google.  So I'm wondering if you may have an `index.php` file in your directory.  If so, then the file does exist and it wouldn't be caught by your conditions.  That's an easy fix, if that's the case.  You can just put this in your `index.php`: `header("Location: register.php");`

Comment: I have my index.php file in the cdsite folder. I have the htaccess file within the register folder, which is a sub directory from cdsite (i.e. domain.com/cdsite/register/.htaccess). Within the register folder is the htaccess file in question and register.php file, which i would like to direct to as soon as someone tries to access anything following the register directory. What you have would work if the htaccess file was in the cdsite. What happens when I enter the empty domain (i.e. www.domain.com/cdsite/register/) is that it shows me files contained within the directory.

Comment: Just to be clear on my previous comment. There is no "index.php" file within the register directory where i have the htaccess file. However, when i enter the URL with the empty directory, it does take me to the index of the directory where it shows which files are contained within the directory.

Comment: Interesting, so no `index` file, yet it still shows a listing of the folder contents.  Try adding this line into your `.htaccess` file: `Options -Indexes`.  That should disallow the contents of the directory from showing and will probably fix the redirect issue.  If that does not fix it, then create an `index.php` file and put this into it: `<?php header("Location: register.php"); exit;`.

Comment: the `code`Options - Indexes`code` Forbids me from accessing the contents of the folder however it doesn't allow the htaccess to take effect either. using the header location doesn't provide me with the desired clean looking url. The solution I guess is to duplicate my register.php file and name it index.php for the times when the directory is accessed "empty". I just don't like having multiple index files around, but it will have to do seeing as how I don't think it is possible to accomplish what it is I would like to. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 Options -Indexes
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^register/$ /cdsite/register/register.php [L]
</IfModule>` fsor an htaccess file placed in my cdsite directory should fix that problem should it not? Why wouldn't this be working?

Comment: For those who may have read this far down i found the solution to the problem. I cannot redirect from an input that has a actual directory existing with the same name because of the order of operations performed. My gerry rigging solution was to rename the directory so that i could use register. My code:
`RewriteEngine On`
`Options -Indexes`
`RewriteBase /cdsite/`
`RewriteRule ^register/?$ /cdsite/reg/register.php [L]`