# How show contents if the folder does not contain index.php/.html using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, redirect, directory, url-rewriting

My set of folders looks like this:

```
server
--public
----index.php
----/items/
------index.php
------template.php
------/folder1/
------/folder2/
------/folder3/
--------index.php
------/folder4/
```

When this happens, folder3 in the browser shows the content at site.com/items/folder3/.

My task is to display in /folder1/, /folder2/, /folder4/ the content from the file site.com/items/template.php (because these folders do not contain index.php or index.html). How can I do this?

===========================

I tried this way, but it has disadvantages - These rules also work with non-existent directories (as /items/aaa/bbb/zzz/), which is inappropriate for me.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index\.html !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index\.htm !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index\.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ template.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22412283/2118611

You should rewrite your empty folders to template.php

Try something like this:

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to template.php
RewriteRule .* /items/template.php [L]
```

**EDIT:**

To check if index file exist you can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.php !-f
RewriteRule . /template.php [L]
```

The above code
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` check if the requested uri is not a file.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` check if the requested uri is a directory.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.php !-f` check if the index.php is not found.

Then redirect to `/template.php`

Comment: Thank you, but in my case, I need to make check that it is the index files. Folders are not empty, at least contain json and pictures

Comment: Check my edited answer again. I think it will fulfill your needs.